# VB.Net ListView Restrict Column Resize If Width = 0

Tags: vb.net, listview, resize

Just want to ask how to

`restrict the column resizing if the current width of column is 0.`

Anyone can help me about this..

Answer (score 2):

Himal's answer works, but it allows the user to resize the column and then the column is snapped back to its original width. To disable the column's width changing at all:

```
Private Sub ListView1_ColumnWidthChanging(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.ColumnWidthChangingEventArgs) Handles ListView1.ColumnWidthChanging
    If Me.ListView1.Columns(e.ColumnIndex).Width = 0 Then
        e.Cancel = True
        e.NewWidth = Me.ListView1.Columns(e.ColumnIndex).Width
    End If
End Sub
```

Note that this code will also affect any columns that the user resizes down to 0 width. It might be useful to change the If statement to check for specific columns, depending on your needs.

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this?

```
Dim preWidth As Integer = 1

Private Sub ListView1_ColumnWidthChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.ColumnWidthChangedEventArgs) Handles ListView1.ColumnWidthChanged


    If preWidth = 0 Then ListView1.Columns(0).Width = 0

    preWidth = ListView1.Columns(0).Width


End Sub
```